# Кластеризация объектов на карте Google

Tags: android, google-maps

Нужно кластеризовать маркеры которые накладываются друг на друга.
Может кто нибудь писал уже такой алгоритм и сможет поделится?

p.s. тут нужен алгоритм именно когда маркеры накладываются друг на друга.

Comment: Просто возьмите уже готовую гугловую библиотеку для этого: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: Стандартные алгоритмы разве умеют кластиризовывать по пересекаемым маркерам? Они же как то по расстоянии вроде работают, и еще непонятно как влияет масштаб (Zoom). p.s. маркеры не стандартного капельного вида.